# SSIS Transformation level logging

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssis

Is it possible to log all the transformations in SSIS? I have a custom logging solution which logs the data for each of the control flow element. But I would like to do so at the transformation level if it is possible. If not, thats ok...but I'd still like to know if its possible or not.

For example, if the package was to fail at the lookup, could I have the exact reason for why it failed and what data it failed on? Additionally, the outputs of the Source, Derived column and etc. 
[image]

Comment: Could you provide an example of what you are hoping to accomplish with this? Are you looking for row counts, throughput of a given transformation, something else?

Comment: I added more information. I just need to find out the different information (statistics) of each transformation. For example on the lookup transformation, how many rows entered and how many went out either way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found answer to this. On the canned logging (that comes along with SSIS) you can select a property called "PipeLineComponentTime". This gives the component wise execution time in milliseconds. Only thing is, you will have to filter out the information from your tables because of the amount of log that this would generate.[image]

Comment: I'm not familiar with that one. OnPipelineRowsSent can be handy if you are looking to find the bottlenecks in a given dataflow. [This post](http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/jamesn/archive/2008/02/11/60504.aspx) has a query to breakdown those events to generate throughput timings